# Horizontal View pager not working after scrolling the gridview in the pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on an Android app which implements Horizontal View Pager. I have a grid view in one view. Swipe is not working after I scroll the gridview. It is working correct til I scroll the gridview.
I used the following code.

```
mPager = (HorizontalPager) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_pager);
mPager.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);
mPager.setCurrentScreen(1,false);
private final HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener =
    new HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScreenSwitched(final int screen) 
        {
            switch (screen) 
            {
                case 0:

                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:
                   loadScreen3();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

      public void loadScreen3()
        {
        CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter=new CustomGridViewAdapter(this,R.layout.row_grid,gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: I have edited the question.please check.